# Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined - with vue multiselect

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

so im having an error on VUE-MULTISELECT

this is my code

```
 <b-modal id="skills">
            <div>
                <label class="typo__label">Tagging</label>
                <multiselect v-model="value" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search or add a tag" label="name" track-by="code" :options="options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addTags"></multiselect>
            </div>
            
            <template #modal-footer="{cancel}">
                    <b-button @click="cancel()"  size="sm" variant="success">
                        Add Info
                    </b-button>
            </template>
        </b-modal>
```

this is my code on methods

```
addTags(newTag) {
                const tag = {
                    name: newTag,
                    code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
                }
                this.options.push(tag)
                this.value.push(tag)
            },
```

this the code on my data

```
 value: [],
                options: [
                    { name: 'Vue.js', code: 'vu' },
                    { name: 'Javascript', code: 'js' },
                    { name: 'Open Source', code: 'os' },
                ],
```

and it give me this error

```
app.js:117759 TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined
```

Comment: It could help to see the entire `methods` block

Comment: can you reproduce the problem here- https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-moser-lpjsm?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response and sorry for the trouble. so the problem was that i mispelled one of my methods i have a button that has a @click="contacts" but my method name is only contact. i dont know why it affected the multiselect though, but its working now thanks again

Comment: You helped me with the answer a lot. I had the same error.